# Add str to end of each number in a list

Tags: python, list, path, grasshopper

This is the what I have right now:

```
L1 = range(0,3,1)
num = str(L1)
L2 = ';1'
path = [i + ";1" for i in num]
print(path)
```

which gives me this:

```
['[;1', '0;1', ',;1', ' ;1', '1;1', ',;1', ' ;1', '2;1', '];1']
```

but I want it to look like this:

```
0;1
1;1
2;1
```

The goal is to use this in a grasshopper script to create new paths that can replace existing paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `num = str(L1)` will convert the **entire** `L1` list into a string but you only want to convert the **elements** of `L1` list into string.

Try this:

```
path = [str(i) + ";1" for i in range(0,3,1)]
for line in path:
    print(line)
```

Output:

```
0;1
1;1
2;1
```

Answer (score 1):

Trying to follow your logic, I guess:

```
L1 = [str(i) for i in range(0,3,1)]
#=> ['0', '1', '2']
```

So, putting together:

```
L1 = [str(i) for i in list(range(0,3,1))]
L2 = ';1'
path = [i + L2 for i in L1 ]
print(path)
#=> ['0;1', '1;1', '2;1']
```

Then you can iterate over elements of paths to print it out as you desire.

Answer (score 0):

If you tried `print(num)` after the second line, you would realized that `num = '[0, 1, 2]'` or `num = 'range(0, 3)'` depends on your compiler, and it is already a string. Thats why when you were trying to loop through `num`, you got all those things.

Instead, try:

```
L1 = range(0,3,1)
num = str(L1)
L2 = ';1'
for i in L1:
    print(str(i) + L2)
```

or

```
path = [str(i) + L2 for i in L1]
```

if you want to put them in a single list.